# .net webservice publishing process question

Tags: asp.net, web-services, publish

I have a webservice that exists in an asp.net website.  When I publish the site to a test server I have to go into the bin folder and into the .svc file for the service and manually change the URL to correctly reflect the test server URL.  Is there a better way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always run a build tool to automatically do this for you.